# Округление после четырёх значащих цифр Python

Tags: python, pandas

Имеется следующий результат вычислений:

```
 1.103567  -0.015367  0.000616
-0.023323   1.138369 -0.018582
-0.003442   0.004548  1.195153
```

Устройство преобразует эти числа следующим образом:

```
[1.104, -0.01537, 0.000616, 
 -0.02332, 1.138, -0.01858,
 -0.003442, 0.004548, 1.195]
```

Для дальнейшей работы необходимо сравнивать вычисления и числа внутри устройства, поэтому возникла потребность в округлении результатов вычислений так же, как это делается на устройстве. Round не даёт удовлетворительного результата.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

где `m` это DataFrame.

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под "не даёт удовлетворительного результата" ?

Comment: @AlexeyProkopenko  m.round(3)
                   
  1.104 -0.015  0.001
 -0.023  1.138 -0.019
 -0.003  0.005  1.195

Comment: А какой результат вы хотите получить?

Comment: @AlexeyProkopenko такой как в списке [1.104, -0.01537, 0.000616, -0.02332, 1.138, -0.01858, -0.003442, 0.004548, 1.195]

Comment: то есть вам нужно округлять до 4-ех значащих знаков

Comment: @AlexeyProkopenko  да

Comment: Что такое `m`? (Какой тип: `type(m)`?) Вы вероятно хотите `numpy.allclose(a,b, 1e-4,0)`

Comment: @jfs m - это DataFrame.

Comment: Есть проблемы с использованием `allclose()`? Или вопрос другой?

Comment: @jfs `numpy.allclose(a, b, 1e-3,0)` в данном случае работает. Спасибо, рассмотрю этот вариант

Comment: @ShalomAlecheim: если это работает для вас (я не могу проверить), то опубликуйте в виде своего ответа, [это явно привестствуется](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Можно еще попробовать: `pd.util.testing.assert_almost_equal(m, mat, check_less_precise=False)` или `pd.util.testing.assert_almost_equal(m, mat, check_less_precise=3)`, где `3` - это число знаков после запятой для сравнения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Товарищ в комментариях подсказал еще один хороший способ, который при больших массивах данных гораздо более предпочтителен:
Итак, у нас имеется результат вычислений `m` и данные с устройства `newmatrix`. Их необходимо сравнить.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

m
          0         1         2
0  1.099394 -0.015754  0.006890
1 -0.025979  1.119590 -0.002269
2 -0.021262  0.005393  1.191073

type(m)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

newmatrix
[1.099, -0.01575, 0.00689, -0.02598, 1.12, -0.002269, -0.02126, 0.005393, 1.191]

type(newmatrix)
<type 'list'>
```

Приводим `newmatrix` к формату `DataFrame`

```
mat=np.array(newmatrix)
mat=mat.reshape((3,3))
mat=pd.DataFrame(mat)

mat
         0         1         2
0  1.09900 -0.015750  0.006890
1 -0.02598  1.120000 -0.002269
2 -0.02126  0.005393  1.191000
```

И затем одной функцией производим сравнение:

```
numpy.allclose(m, mat, 1e-3,0)
True
```

Answer (score 1):

Для ваших данных накидал рабочий вариант.

```
import math 

def SpecialRaund(val, n):
    exponent = 0

    while abs(val) < 1:
        val *= 10
        exponent -= 1

    val = round(val, n)
    val *= math.pow(10, exponent)

    return val

print SpecialRaund(1.103567, 3)
print SpecialRaund(-0.015367, 3)
print SpecialRaund(0.000616, 3)
```

Result:

```
1.104
-0.01537
0.000616
```

В SpecialRaund не рассматривается кейс с положительным порядком числа (в терминах мантиса-порядок). Таким образом

```
print SpecialRaund(11035.678934, 3)
```

Result:

```
11035.679
```

но, думаю, вы идею поняли и легко допишите эту функцию

Answer (score 1):

Наткнулся на такой способ:

```
float('%.4g' % 1.195153)
1.195
```

проверил на всех числах, как раз то, что было нужно