# Кубический корень из числа

Tags: python, python-3.x

пишу вот это `64**(1/3)` и думаю, что вы догадались в чем собственно вопрос, короче пишу это выдает вместо нужного "4", 3.999999999... и т.д. Я знаю, что это проблема хранения чисел, что числа никак не представить точно в системе, но как решить мою проблему, которая заключается в том, что мне нужно при любом входном неотрицательном числе правильно выдавался оттуда корень кубический? Если 64, то 4, если 0.001, то 0.1 и т.д
Просьба не отмечать вопрос как дубликат т.к решения конкретно своего вопроса я не нашел на форуме. Спасибо. Если не сложно напишите возможный код решения

Answer (score 3):

[Из комментария на ваш предыдущий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/944980/%d0%98%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5#comment1572857_944980):

```
In [2]: def cube_root(n):
   ...:     return round(n ** (1/3), 7)
   ...:

In [3]: cube_root(64)
Out[3]: 4.0

In [4]: cube_root(0.001)
Out[4]: 0.1

In [5]: cube_root(0.2 ** 3)
Out[5]: 0.2

In [6]: cube_root(0.123 ** 3)
Out[6]: 0.123
```

Answer (score 1):

> при любом входном неотрицательном числе правильно выдавался оттуда
>   корень кубический

Здесь многое зависит от того, что считать правильным значением.

Например, в случае с кубическим корнем из 64 или 0,001 можно использовать округление до одной значащей цифры (**не путать с округлением до 1 знака после запятой!!!**).

[Пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/571227/%D0%9E%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%80%D1%91%D1%85-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80-python) округления до 4 значащих цифр уже обсуждался на ruSO. Возможно, он будет Вам полезен как основа для решения.